React state change was hindered for filtering some data
The duplicate post, have issue like the state change is not reflected immediately. But thats not the issue here, Please read the whole post to understand the problem. Here due to some filtering the state change is hindered, and UPDATE: i have used useEffect() but the it shows the state has changed there in console, but still the Snackbar does not shows. So i have tried a log in the render with trinary operator, there the state change is unchanged like in the definition of the state ( if it was false, it shows false in render, if it was undefiend it show undefined in the render) but though in render it shows unchanged, but simultaneuosly the useEffect shows the state has changed.
I'm encountering an issue with my React application where the state (deleteSuccess) is not updating after a successful deletion operation.
I have a function handleDeleteSubmit that is triggered when a user deletes an item. Inside this function, I make an API call to delete the item. Upon successful deletion (data.error is falsy), I set deleteSuccess state to true. However, even though the deletion is successful, deleteSuccess remains false.
const handleDeleteSubmit = async () => {
  if (!accessToken) {
    return;
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      apiPath.newsletterApi.deleteNewsLetter(newsletter.location.content_id),
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    if (!data.error) {
      console.log("deleted successful:", data);
      setDeleteSuccess(true);
      let cp = currentNewsletters!.filter(
        (news) => news.location.content_id !== newsletter.location.content_id
      );
      setCurrentNewsletters!(cp);
      handleDeleteClose();
    } else {
      setDeleteError(true);
      console.error("Failed to delete:", data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    setDeleteError(true);
    console.error("Error deleting:", error);
  }
};


Despite setting deleteSuccess to true, it still logs false. currentNewsletter is just array of data from props.
Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
code works fine if i comment out this part,
setDeleteSuccess(true);
      let cp = currentNewsletters!.filter(
        (news) => news.location.content_id !== newsletter.location.content_id
      );
      setCurrentNewsletters!(cp);

like this,
if (!data.error) {
        console.log("deleted successful:", data);

        // let cp = currentTemplate!.filter(
        //   (temp) => temp.location.content_id !== template.location.content_id
        // );
        // setCurrentTemplate!(cp);
        // Perform any actions after successful update
        setDeleteSuccess(true);
        console.log(deleteSuccess);
        handleDeleteClose();


why ! in the end of the set state function and state name ?

Have you tried setCurrentTemplate(prev => prev.filter(el => el.location.content_id !== template.location.content_id)); ?

If I may ask, what's this deleteSuccess is used for? It seems redundant to be setting this kind of state?

@Owenn hey mate, thanks for the reply. The use is really simple, i just want to show a MUI Snakebar when the delete is successful, but since the state is stuck at false, the Snackbar is never shown.

Editing only the title isn't sufficient for re-opening a post. You should try to provide more details and explain why or how the marked duplicate doesn't address your issue.

The duplicate post, have issue like the state change is not reflected immediately. But thats not the issue here, Please read the whole post to understand the problem. Here due to some filtering the state change is hindered, and UPDATE: i have used useEffect() but the it shows the state has changed there in console, but still the Snackbar does not shows. So i have tried a log in the render with trinary operator, there the state change is unchanged like in the definition of the state but though in render it shows unchanged, but simultaneuosly the useEffect shows the state has changed. @DrewReese

We have only the information you provide in the post, what toast are you referring to? This is what a complete [mcve] would include and cover.

@DrewReese its frustrating man, like you flaged it as duplicate post and when i explained it, it would not been necessary if you read the full post, all that you can come up with is minimal reproducible example. You didn't get what i just said, how can you flag it as duplicate post.

Like was stated, we have only the information you provide to go on. If you have some issue elsewhere triggering/displaying/rendering a toast/snackbar element/component/ui then please [edit] the post to clearly explain why and how this problem is different than the duplicate and provide a clear and complete [mcve] of the relevant code you have a problem with.
